# mysql JOIN not select the answers if there is no votes

Tags: mysql

see this code

```
SELECT x.*, z.rates 
FROM poll_answers x
  JOIN 
    (SELECT answer_id, COUNT( id ) AS `rates`
     FROM poll_votes 
     GROUP BY answer_id) z 
  ON 
    x.id = z.answer_id
WHERE x.poll_id = '$poll_id' 
ORDER BY x.id DESC
```

it just show the answer is it has more then 0 votes, this mean if my poll is new and there is not votes it will never show the answers

so the question how to update this code to show the answers if has no vots too

Answer (score 2):

You must do a `LEFT JOIN` instead of just a `JOIN` :

```
SELECT x.*, z.rates 
FROM poll_answers x
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT answer_id, COUNT( id ) AS `rates`
     FROM poll_votes 
     GROUP BY answer_id) z 
  ON 
    x.id = z.answer_id
WHERE x.poll_id = '$poll_id' 
ORDER BY x.id DESC
```

`JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` is used to join two tables and keeps only the rows which are present on both side.

`LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows on the left table (the table in the `FROM` clause) and add informations from the right table (the table you're joining with) when possible

`RIGHT JOIN` keeps all the rows from the right table and add informations from the left table when possible.

In your case, since you want all the `poll_answers` you must use `LEFT JOIN`.

Be aware that `rates` will be `null` instead of 0 when there's no vote. You can replace the first line with this `SELECT x.*, CASE z.rates IS NULL 0 ELSE z.rates` if you want to have 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.*, z.rates 
FROM poll_answers x
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT answer_id, COUNT( id ) AS `rates`
     FROM poll_votes 
     GROUP BY answer_id) z 
  ON 
    x.id = z.answer_id
WHERE x.poll_id = '$poll_id' 
ORDER BY x.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT x . * , z.rates  
FROM poll_answers x   
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT answer_id, COUNT( id ) AS `rates`      
FROM poll_votes       
GROUP BY answer_id) z    
       ON   x.id = z.answer_id 
WHERE x.poll_id = '$poll_id'  ORDER BY x.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the answer posted, if you are filtering for a single query, you should - for performance reasons - add the `poll_answers` to the grouping sub query, since you only want to count the votes for a single poll, not the entire table.

The inner query should look like this:

```
(SELECT v.answer_id, COUNT( v.id ) AS `rates`
FROM poll_answers a JOIN poll_votes v 
    ON a.answer_id = v.answer_id
WHERE a.poll_id = '$poll_id' 
GROUP BY v.answer_id)
```